# controlador para mostrar contenido del la base datos en symfony3?

Tags: html, controller, symfony

hola buenas tengo guardado en la base de datos ,codigos completos html, necesito a traves de un controlador mostrar el resultado del codigo en un pagina nueva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuperas el contenido en el contralador en una variable como cadena de texto:

```
$html=$em->getRepository('MyEntityRepository')->findOne();
```

Luego lo pasas como parametro cuando renderizas la nueva página en el controlador.

```
return $this->render('ruta a la pagina/nueva_pagina.html.twig',['html'=>$html]);
```

Luego lo renderizas en la página con twig.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        {{ html }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, pero es mejor esperar a que el autor edite la pregunta añadiendo más informacion y lo que ha intentado. Asi le ayudamos con su problema concreto y no le hacemos la tarea. Un saludo

Comment: gracias  era lo que necesitaba!!